# CNTK - Weight update composes 90% of slow training time

Tags: python, performance, machine-learning, gpu, cntk

When profiling CNTK training a variant of Alexnet, the results were as follows:

```
Description................ ............Mean ..........StdDev .............Min .............Max ...........Count ...........Total

Main Thread

_Minibatch Iteration      :      4379.453 ms       401.522 ms      3984.586 ms      7079.859 ms               64     00:04:40.285
__Forward + Backward      :       467.035 ms       375.025 ms       407.861 ms      3443.404 ms               64     29890.221 ms
__Weight Update           :      3912.241 ms       214.278 ms      3570.211 ms      4104.718 ms               64     00:04:10.383

Data Reader
```

The weight update forms the majority of the training time, when using both SGD and Momentum SGD:

```
learner = momentum_sgd(ot.parameters, 0.015,0.9,gaussian_noise_injection_std_dev=0.0000001)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of gaussian noise injection, this bottlenecks the GPU by waiting on the CPU to provide the random values needed. Removing the parameter solves this:

```
learner = momentum_sgd(ot.parameters, 0.015,0.9)
```